# Prove that a curve is not rectifiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

As a parameter curve in $R^n$ is rectifiable iff it is B.V. with each coordinates, I've been trying to prove $(x,f(x))$ is not rectifiable, while $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}\{10^ix\},$ defined on [0,1], where $\{\}$ is the decimal part function by constructing a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with unbounded variation. But I failed. Could anyone help?

Comment: In which interval is $x$ supposed to lie?

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot writting it, it is [0,1]

Comment: OK. Can you update your question? Thanks.

Comment: OK...I've already rectified it.